# Split string with regex with numbers problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Having a list of strings like:

```
Client Potential XSS2Medium
Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium
Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low
```

I would like to split every string into three strings like:

```
["Client Potential XSS", "2", "Medium"]
```

I use this regular expression:

```
/[a-zA-Z ]+|[0-9]+/g)
```

But with strings that contains others numbers into, it obviously doesn't work. For example with:

```
Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium
```

the result is:

```
["Client HTML", "5", " Insercure Storage", "41", "Medium"]
```

I can't find the regex that produces:

```
["Client HTML5 Insercure Storage", "41", "Medium"]
```

This regex works on regex101.com:

```
(.+[ \t][A-z]+)+([0-9]+)+([A-z]+)
```

Using it in my code:

```
data.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
        .split("\r\n") // Split the vulnerabilities
        .filter(item => !item.match(/(-+)Page \([0-9]+\) Break(-+)/g) // Remove page break
          && !item.match(/PAGE [0-9]+ OF [0-9]+/g) // Remove pagination
          && item !== '') // Remove blank strings
        .map(v => v.match(/(.+[ \t][A-z]+)+([0-9]+)+([A-z]+)/g));
```

doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
All strings end with `High`, `Medium` and `Low`.

Comment: Your strings end up with `Low`, `Medium` and `High` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, all strings end with `High`, `Medium` or `Low`. I updated my question.

Comment: What is the original string in data? It looks like you are doing a lot before trying to make that last match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `g` global flag.

Remove that flag from this line: `.map(v => v.match(/(.+[ \t][A-z]+)+([0-9]+)+([A-z]+)/g));` to make it:

`.map(v => v.match(/(.+[ \t][A-z]+)+([0-9]+)+([A-z]+)/));`

---

Also, you could make the regex much simpler, as [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790738/1078008) by @bhmahler:

`.map(v => v.match(/(.*?)(\d+)(low|medium|high)/i));`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should give you what you are looking for.

```
/(.*?)(\d+)(low|medium|high)/gi
```

Here is an example https://regex101.com/r/AS9mvf/1

Here is an example of it working with map

```js
var entries = [
  'Client Potential XSS2Medium',
  'Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium',
  'Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low'
];

var matches = entries.map(v => {
  var result = /(.*?)(\d+)(low|medium|high)/gi.exec(v);
  return [
    result[1],
    result[2],
    result[3]
  ];
});

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thank you but in my code it doesn't work. I think it's a problem of the `map` function, because I've others regex that work on regex101 but not in my code.

Comment: I would check and see what the values are in the map function.  Regex is regex, it should match, if it's not, are you sure your strings are in the format you posted?

Comment: if it is working on `regex101 ` it should work else where.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workaround (that is match vs. capture, then replace):

```js
let strings = ['Client Potential XSS2Medium', 'Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium', 'Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low', 'Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium'];

let regex = /(?:HTML5|or_other_string)|(\d+)/g;

strings.forEach(function(string) {
    string = string.replace(regex, function(match, g1) {
        if (typeof(g1) != "undefined") {
            return "#@#" + g1 + "#@#";
        }
        return match;
    });
    string = string.split("#@#");
    console.log(string);
});
```

See an additional [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YtgHJB/1).

Comment: I don't know what type of string could be there. It should be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: @Alesanco: I guess that this approach is rather flexible - you could alter other exceptions here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one solution that wraps the number before the words `High`, `Low` or `Medium` with a custom `token` using `String.replace()` and finally split the resulting string by this `token`:

```js
const inputs = [
  "Client Potential XSS2High",
  "Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium",
  "Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low"
];

let token = "-#-";
let regexp = /(\d+)(High|Low|Medium)$/;

let res = inputs.map(
    x => x.replace(regexp, `${token}$1${token}$2`).split(token)
);

console.log(res);
```

Another solution is to use this regexp: `/^(.*?)(\d+)(High|Low|Medium)$/i`

```js
const inputs = [
  "Client Potential XSS2High",
  "Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium",
  "Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low"
];

let regexp = /^(.*?)(\d+)(High|Low|Medium)$/i;

let res = inputs.map(
    x => x.match(regexp).slice(1)
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ["Client Potential XSS2Medium",
"Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium",
"Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low"];    

let re = /^.+[a-zA-Z](?=\d+)|\d+(?=[A-Z])|[^\d]+\w+$/g;


arr.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(re)))
```

`^.+[a-zA-Z](?=\d+)` Match beginning of string followed by `a-zA-Z` followed by one or more digit characters

`\d+(?=[A-Z])` Match one or more digit characters followed by uppercase letter character

`[^\d]+\w+$` Negate digit characters followed by matching word characters until end of string

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = `Client Potential XSS2Medium
Client HTML5 Insecure Storage41Medium
Client Potential DOM Open Redirect12Low`


const res = text.split("\n").map(el =>  el.replace(/\d+/g, a => ' ' + a + ' ') );

console.log(res)
```